# how to load script dynamically in html pages without using code?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, load

I have some issue when loading script dynamically.
I know we can use method like .appendChild function or any.
but can I have another way?

like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/constants/Constants_{{ _lang }}.js"></script>
```

where _lang is variable containing user language.
I know this is possible with angular but I wanted to do without it. Is it possible?
if yes then How?

Comment: `I have some issue` Please be specific

Comment: Share the code you tried so far with the issue you're having ?